# php showing wrong time after daylight savings

Tags: php, date, dst

I have a PHP program that lets employees clock in/out every day. Since daylight savings, it's showing the users as clocking in and out an hour later than they actually did. here's an example:

```
<?php
    echo 'Now:       '. date('h:i:s a') ."\n";
    echo "Timestamp: " . date('U') . "\n";
?>
```

it's currently 11:45. it's showing 12:45 as the result. any ideas why this would be happening?

**EDIT**

The code above is not part of the timeclock. It's just an example i'm using to show that it's giving incorrect results. Timezone has no bearing on the result. If i use GMT, it still shows an hour ahead of what it should be. and it worked yesterday, so...

Comment: i see im not the only one with this problem

Comment: What does `var_dump(date_default_timezone_set('EST'));` display?

Comment: var_dump(date_default_timezone_set('EST')); shows the following result: bool(true)

Comment: I have a feeling you removed the wrong line in your last edit. You probably wanted to get rid of `$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);` as that is unrelated to the rest of the code.

Comment: i edited again. the code above is what im running, and its showing an hour ahead of what it should be. it wasnt showing an hour ahead until last night, which is when we switched clocks for DST. the timezone is completely irrelevant

Comment: Is the server's clock off by 1 hour?

Comment: if i type date in bash, it shows the correct time

Answer (score 2):

Set your default timezone to something that PHP recognizes. here is NY:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

DST/STD time will be handled automatically.

Comment: Timezone has no bearing on the result

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your timezone to "EST" which according to this list in the PHP documentation about timezones (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php).  You should not be using.

Rather you should set your timezone to a location off of this list (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)